# Angular4 date formatting issue with timezone

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I get date from json response as `"createTimestamp":"2019-01-22T18:57:47+08:00"`. This is singapore timestamp.
I wanted to show only Singapore time irrespective of location accessed.

Now, the problems is that, date is being converted to the format specified but with local timezone.

Actual timestamp: `2019-01-22T18:57:47+08:00 (singapore time)`
when accessed from India : `22 Jan 2019 16:27`
when accessed from Singapore : `22 Jan 2019 18:57`

I tried date: `'dd MMM yyyy HH:mm'` didn't solve mytimezone issue.

I wanted to use custom date pipe to convert it to `dd MMM yyyy HH:mm` format

Comment: You can try use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) and [Moment Timezone js](https://momentjs.com/timezone/).

Comment: Thanks @MinhNguyen. `var dateStrM =moment(dateStr).utcOffset(UTC_OFFSET_SG).format(pattern);` This worked for me. where `const UTC_OFFSET_SG = '+0800';`